# Fast string counting in dplyr

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, purrr

I need to count instances of a pattern (fixed) within a string that's held in a column in a tibble. `mutate(x = str_count(col, pattern))` does exactly what I want but it's not fast enough to process the volume of strings I have to evaluate.

#### Simplified tibble

```
test = tibble(
  id=c(1,2,3),
  seq=c("ATCG","ATTT","CGCG")
)
```

#### Works but is too slow in microbenchmark testing

```
test %>% mutate(CpG = str_count(seq, "CG"))
```

#### Theoretically faster on single sequences but not working on my tibble column

This just gives the single value of the first row's count

```
test %>% mutate(CpG = sum(gregexpr("CG", seq, fixed=TRUE)[[1]] > 0))
```

I tried to get purrr::map to work, but I'm failing at it...here are my attempts that won't run:

```
test %>% mutate(CpG = map(~sum(gregexpr("CG", seq, fixed=TRUE)[[1]] > 0)))
test %>% mutate(CpG = map(seq, ~sum(gregexpr("CG", .x, fixed=TRUE)[[1]] > 0)))
```

## Edit: Time Benchmarks

Looks like `stringi::stri_count_fixed` is the optimal choice on the test set.

```
microbenchmark(
  mutate(test, CpG = stringr::str_count(seq, "CG")),
  mutate(test, CpG = purrr::map_int(seq, ~sum(gregexpr("CG", .x, fixed=TRUE)[[1]] > 0))),
  mutate(test, CpG = Biostrings::vcountPattern("CG", DNAStringSet(seq))),
  mutate(test, CpG = lengths(regmatches(seq, gregexpr("CG", seq)))),
  mutate(test, CpG = stringi::stri_count_fixed(seq,"CG"))
)  
Unit: microseconds
                                                                                          expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
                                             mutate(test, CpG = stringr::str_count(seq, "CG")) 125.502 133.9995 159.0844 147.9045 164.2925  441.242   100
 mutate(test, CpG = purrr::map_int(seq, ~sum(gregexpr("CG", .x,      fixed = TRUE)[[1]] > 0))) 167.210 183.4695 215.7746 202.8890 230.5275  450.177   100
                        mutate(test, CpG = Biostrings::vcountPattern("CG", DNAStringSet(seq))) 789.889 827.3810 955.8919 887.3400 989.7415 1845.212   100
                             mutate(test, CpG = lengths(regmatches(seq, gregexpr("CG", seq)))) 150.315 159.4750 178.9039 169.1840 185.1345  316.479   100
                                      mutate(test, CpG = stringi::stri_count_fixed(seq, "CG")) 112.015 120.6615 131.4281 125.0470 135.4330  213.184   100
```

And, here are the results with one portion of my real data (~20,000 instances of 1500 nt sequences) run on a remote server with ~3X the available RAM and cores of my initial run. I continue to be impressed with `stringi`'s implementation, which somehow read through everything in blazing 20-something milliseconds.

```
Unit: milliseconds
                                                                                          expr        min         lq       mean     median        uq        max neval
                                             mutate(test, CpG = stringr::str_count(seq, "CG"))  402.55513  408.04101  419.82213  414.31085  425.4113  481.08128   100
 mutate(test, CpG = purrr::map_int(seq, ~sum(gregexpr("CG", .x,      fixed = TRUE)[[1]] > 0)))  429.84148  436.02402  474.08864  438.84198  447.3058 1054.48253   100
                        mutate(test, CpG = Biostrings::vcountPattern("CG", DNAStringSet(seq)))  301.26062  309.76674  310.97071  310.08229  310.8837  336.12834   100
                             mutate(test, CpG = lengths(regmatches(seq, gregexpr("CG", seq)))) 1981.78309 1990.84206 2050.41928 1999.07389 2020.3675 2980.62566   100
                                      mutate(test, CpG = stringi::stri_count_fixed(seq, "CG"))   23.33313   23.55215   23.90881   23.66268   23.8916   27.40499   100
```

Since I could run this on the native DNAStringSet since my data starts out as a GRanges object, I microbenchmarked the vector of sequences, too, and got ranges in the 240-250 ms ballpark.

I have another use-case coming up with 1,000-100,000 nt long sequences with longer search patterns and will plan to update with those results when I move back to that project.

Comment: You should try `stringi::stri_count_fixed` which is known to be much faster than its `stringr` counterparts.

Comment: Nice benchmark analysis (+1); Curious: the target sequences are very short here though. Is this a realistic scenario? `vmatchPattern` will be more efficient for long target sequences (see my `microbenchmark` analysis below).

Comment: Not at all. :) My plan was to benchmark it on my set of sequences (I'll get it running before bed) and choose the one that ran fastest on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `stri_count_fixed` from `stringi` library which is known to be faster than it's `stringr` counterparts.

```
test %>% mutate(CpG = stringi::stri_count_fixed(seq, 'CG'))

#     id seq     CpG
#  <dbl> <chr> <int>
#1     1 ATCG      1
#2     2 ATTT      0
#3     3 CGCG      2
```

---

Apart from that you can use `map_int` which will return an integer vector as compared to `map` which returns a list to use it with `gregexpr`.

```
library(dplyr)

test %>% 
  mutate(CpG = purrr::map_int(seq, ~sum(gregexpr("CG", .x, fixed=TRUE)[[1]] > 0)))
```

Or another option is `regmatches` with `gregexpr`.

```
test %>% mutate(CpG = lengths(regmatches(seq, gregexpr("CG", seq))))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Biostrings::vcountPattern`

```
library(Biostrings)
test %>% mutate(CpG = vcountPattern("CG", DNAStringSet(seq)))
#  # A tibble: 3 x 3
#     id seq     CpG
#  <dbl> <chr> <int>
#1     1 ATCG      1
#2     2 ATTT      0
#3     3 CGCG      2
```

`Biostrings::vcountPattern` is considerably faster than the `str_count` solution for a vector of longer (DNA) strings; here are some `microbenchmark` results

```
# Sample data
df <- tibble(
    id = 1:100,
    seq = replicate(
        100,
        paste0(sample(c("A", "C", "G", "T"), 100000, replace = T), collapse = "")))


library(microbenchmark)
res <- microbenchmark(
    str_count = df %>% mutate(CpG = str_count(seq, "CG")),
    vmatchPattern = df %>% mutate(CpG = vcountPattern("CG", DNAStringSet(seq))))
#Unit: milliseconds
#          expr       min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#     str_count 156.37642 162.1629 167.2005 164.4958 169.2456 251.3426   100
# vmatchPattern  95.68998 102.4176 108.2428 105.2501 108.5511 322.3143   100

library(ggplot2)
autoplot(res)
```

[image]

Comment: How do I install this package? `install.packages('Biostrings')` gives me `package ‘Biostrings’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)` I checked this website https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biostrings.html and used `BiocManager::install("Biostrings")` which gave `Error: Bioconductor version '3.8' requires R version '3.5';`

Comment: Bioconductor should be compatible with 3.6.1; you'll just have to install it and then use it's package manager to install Biostrings.

Comment: @GenesRus Yes, I just noticed:-) If you're working more with DNA sequences I can really recommend taking a look at the `Biostrings` functions (and possibly functions from other relevant Bioconductor packages). They will make your life a lot easier, and a lot of their methods have been optimised for "typical" Bioinformatics tasks.

Comment: @RonakShah It's probably not advisable but you should be able to install `Biostrings` on older R version (< 3.5.0) with `source("http://www.bioconductor.org/biocLite.R"); biocLite("Biostrings")`. [UPDATE] On re-reading your first comment, I believe you need to update Bioconductor first. Then use `BiocManager::install("Biostrings")`.

Comment: @GenRus No it isn't compatible for R version 3.6.1 running under macOS Catalina 10.15.2; Bioconductor version '3.10' shows 83 packages out-of-date and Biostrings will not install.

Answer (score 1):

Using @MauritsEvers test dataset `df`, you can use oligoNucleotideFrequency in Biostrings.

```
library(Biostrings)
head(oligonucleotideFrequency(DNAStringSet(df$seq),2))
       AA   AC   AG   AT   CA   CC   CG   CT   GA   GC   GG   GT   TA   TC   TG
[1,] 6402 6147 6351 6190 6129 6081 6180 6232 6311 6222 6323 6341 6249 6172 6342
[2,] 6305 6320 6295 6217 6379 6253 6139 6291 6227 6279 6239 6163 6225 6210 6235
[3,] 6284 6352 6305 6133 6211 6293 6356 6231 6374 6286 6280 6202 6205 6160 6201
[4,] 6217 6253 6265 6300 6189 6296 6302 6175 6379 6275 6207 6195 6251 6137 6282
[5,] 6346 6315 6217 6291 6289 6060 6254 6223 6269 6203 6313 6259 6264 6248 6260
[6,] 6066 6216 6282 6286 6376 6339 6223 6156 6216 6235 6360 6241 6193 6304 6186
       TT
[1,] 6327
[2,] 6222
[3,] 6126
[4,] 6276
[5,] 6188
[6,] 6320
```

We just get the "CG" column:

```
library(microbenchmark)
res <- microbenchmark(
    str_count = df %>% mutate(CpG = str_count(seq, "CG")),
    vmatchPattern = df %>% mutate(CpG = vcountPattern("CG", DNAStringSet(seq))),
    oligo=df %>% mutate(CpG = oligonucleotideFrequency(DNAStringSet(seq),2)[,"CG"])
)

> res
Unit: milliseconds
          expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
     str_count 129.73744 135.05308 140.01877 139.11458 144.47085 158.9793   100
 vmatchPattern  82.30784  88.48554  92.13986  93.01389  95.53329 107.3482   100
         oligo  57.25595  62.11515  67.63134  64.50559  66.99784 349.3443   100
 cld
   c
  b 
 a
```

You already know what bases or dinucleotide to expect, so it's a matter of counting rather than string matching, making this faster.